# Выпадающий список с контекстным поиском

Tags: php, javascript, html

Есть, следующий код:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" list="test" placeholder="Пример" name="test">
    <datalist id="test">
    <?php foreach ($test as $item) { ?>
          <option value="<?= $item['ID'] ?>"><?= $item['TITLE'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </datalist>
```

Все работает, но при выборе элемента по его названию отображается в поле его id соответственно, а желательно увидеть его имя, а уже при передаче в форму отправить id. Каким образом это лучше реализовать, может есть другие варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете добавить `input` с типом `hidden` и записывать в него id который соответствует значению из `<option>`.

Так же учтите что ваш главный `input` является `type="text"` и пользовательский ввод может не соответствовать значениям из `<datalist>` и вам необходимо будет учесть это на стороне PHP.

Обратите внимание на [пример](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist#Examples), в нем тег `<option>` без закрывающих тегов, я бы рекомендовал вам придерживаться этого стандарта при использовании `<datalist >`.

**Пример кода**

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="test"]').on('input', function() {
    var idDataList = $(this).attr('list');
    var option = $('#' + idDataList + ' option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]');
    var selectedId = option.length ? option.attr('data-id') : null;
    var hidden = $('input[name="testId"]');
    hidden.val(selectedId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control autocomplete" autocomplete="off" list="test" placeholder="Пример" name="test">
<input type="hidden" name="testId" />

<datalist id="test">
  <option data-id="1" value="Title 1">
  <option data-id="2" value="Title 2">
  <option data-id="3" value="Title 3">
  <option data-id="4" value="Title 4">
  <option data-id="5" value="Title 5">
</datalist>
```

Если вы хотите избежать ситуации когда пользовательский ввод не соответствует значениям из выпадающего списка рекомендую использовать для этого [плагин](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage).

Пример кода взят [от сюда.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26103769/7678419)